# Как проверить количество уникальных значений в двух датафреймах в колонках попарно?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть два датафрейма, train и test, имена колонок одинаковы. В каждом по 80 колонок. Как проверить, равно ли количество уникальных значений первой колонки первого датафрейма количеству уникальных значений первой колонки второго датафрейма, второй колонки первого датафрейма - количеству во второй колонке второго датафрейма? Интересуют только тип данных 'object'

Comment: если колонки одинаковые, то можно попробовать что-то вроде этого: `[train[col].nunique()==test[col].nunique() for col in train.columns[:2]]`

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score 0):

```py
X_unique_values = [i for i in X.columns if X[i].dtype == 'object']
for i in X_unique:
  print(X[i].nunique() == X_test[i].nunique())
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]